# Gson FieldNamingStrategy with multiple policies

Tags: java, gson

I want to map underscored field(such as `this_field_to_mapped`) to camelcase(`thisFieldToMapped`).

So I created `Gson` object with `GsonBuilder` and coded a new class implemented `FieldNamingStrategy` and `SomeClass`.

And I'd run `Gson.fromJson` from `{"thisItem" : "hello", "this_field_to_mapped":1}`, but console log had printed out like this.

> replaced : thisItem
>   replaced : thisFieldToMapped
>   hello
>   0

`thisItem` was mapped well, however `thisFieldToMapped` had printed 0.

How can I map underscored field to camelcase ?

here's my code.

> SomeClass

```
public static class SomeClass {
    public String thisItem;
    public int thisFieldToMapped;
}
```

> UnderScoreToUpper

```
public static class UnderScoreToUpper implements FieldNamingStrategy {

    public String translateName(Field f) {
        String name = f.getName();

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[_][a-z]{1}");

        Matcher m = p.matcher(name);

        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println("matched : " + m.group(0));
            String c = m.group(0).replace("_", "").toUpperCase();
            name = name.replace(m.group(0), c);
        }

        System.out.println("replaced : " + name);

        return name;
    }

}
```

And this is main method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String gsonString = "{\"thisItem\" : \"hello\", \"this_field_to_mapped\":1}";

    Gson g = new GsonBuilder()
            .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
            .setFieldNamingStrategy(new UnderScoreToUpper())
            .serializeSpecialFloatingPointValues().setPrettyPrinting()
            .serializeNulls().create();

    SomeClass c = g.fromJson(gsonString, SomeClass.class);

    if (c != null) {
        System.out.println(c.thisItem);
        System.out.println(c.thisFieldToMapped);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing this backwards. The javadoc for [`FieldNamingStrategy`](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/FieldNamingStrategy.html) states

> A mechanism for providing custom field naming in Gson. This allows the
>   client code to translate field names into a particular convention that
>   is not supported as a normal Java field declaration rules.

Also, the javadoc of [`FieldNamingStrategy#translateName(String)`](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/FieldNamingStrategy.html#translateName-java.lang.reflect.Field-) states

> Translates the field name into its JSON field name representation.

As you can tell, what you receive as an argument to `translateName` is the `Field` itself. `translateName` is meant to convert the name of that field to a name that will appear in the JSON.

So you need to convert `thisFieldToMapped` to `this_field_to_mapped`. You're attempting to do the opposite.

If all your JSON members were named with underscores, you could use `FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES` as a strategy.

Comment: Can I ask one more thing?  I tried also `setFieldNamingPolicy` with `FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES` then `thisFieldToMapped` presents well but `thisItem` presents to null. In this case, What should I do ?

Comment: @MinkyuKim You won't be able to resolve this with `FieldNamingStrategy` if your member names have mixed formats. You either have underscores or camel case (or whatever else), you can't have both.

Comment: Json member naming in disorder is my problem. Not all fields are underscored.

Comment: @MinkyuKim If it's only for one type, use `@SerializedName` with the specific expected name. If it's for multiple types, will multiple different naming pattern, you're out of luck with `FieldNamingStrategy`. You might be able to use a custom `JsonDeserializer`, get a member from the `JsonElement` and introspect the given `Type` to find a matching field with multiple policies.

Comment: Appriciate your kindness. Thank you once again.